# why cannot Apache POI get my selected color with rgb

Tags: java, apache-poi

I get color with rgb with method below

```
public short getRGBColor(int red, int green, int blue){
        HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFPalette palette = hwb.getCustomPalette();
        return palette.findSimilarColor(red,green, blue).getIndex();
    }
```

then call in method below

```
   public CellStyle createStyles(Workbook wb){
    CellStyle style;
    Font font1 = wb.createFont();
            font1.setBold(false);
            style = wb.createCellStyle();
            style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            style.setFillForegroundColor(getRGBColor(211,225,237));
            style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            style.setFont(font1);
        return  style;
}
```

this is my has selected color code 211,225,237
[image]

but getRGBColor method return another color code 204,204,255
[image]

Answer (score 1):

as per the docs, the parameter for `setFillForegroundColor` can be an indexed value from the Enum `IndexedColors` or `setFillBackgroundColor(XSSFColor color)`.

Try to use `setRGB` from XSSFColor class

[XSSFColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html)

Sample code -

```
headerCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFPalette.html#findSimilarColor-int-int-int-), the method `findSimilarColor`finds the closest matching color in the custom palette. You can try to get the exact color with the method `findColor`. But be aware, that the method `findColor` can return `null`.